# Determinant of a block skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices, triangularization

If I have a matrix of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix}$$

where all blocks are square and have the same dimensions, how do I turn it into something like

$$\begin{pmatrix} X & Y \\ 0 & Z \end{pmatrix}$$

so that the determinant is easy to calculate using row and column operations?

Comment: Apologies, I deleted my answer. It was incorrect because the $\LaTeX$ didn't render correctly in your question for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By diagonalization in the $2\times 2$ case, we obtain the similarity relation
$$
\pmatrix{A&-B\\B&A}=\pmatrix{-iI&iI\\I&I}\pmatrix{A-iB&0\\0&A+iB}\pmatrix{(i/2)I&(1/2)I\\-(i/2)I&(1/2)I}.
$$
Whence
$$
\det \pmatrix{A&-B\\B&A}=\det(A-iB)\det(A+iB)=\det(A^2+i(AB-BA)+B^2).
$$
If $A$ and $B$ commute, this yields $\det(A^2+B^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

By using [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), the determinant of your block matrix can be calculated as $\det(A)\det(A+BA^{-1}B)$ if $A$ is invertible, or $\det(B)\det(B+AB^{-1}A)$ if $B$ is invertible. In the course of derivation of these formulae, the matrix is first converted to a block upper triangular form. See the above-linked Wikipedia article for details.

Edit: If you want a method that works in all cases or know nothing about $A$ and $B$ in advance, I think you'd better compute the determinant directly, rather than converting it into a block triangular matrix first, and then evaluating the determinants of the diagonal blocks individually. If you insist in turning the matrix into a block upper triangular form, you may perform an [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) (see also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Decomposition_methods)), but then the resulting matrices are triangular (which, of course, are also *block* triangular). You may consider other matrix decompositions as well (such as QR decomposition or singular value decomposition).

Comment: couldn't it be that nither is invertible?

Comment: @IzikGolan Yes, in that case neither formula is applicable.

Comment: so what can I do in that case? the question didn't state any of them being invertible