# proof about deteminant of a complex linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

say I have a linear space $V$ over $\Bbb C$ and a linear transformation $T:V \to V$
such that $T=A+iB$ where $A,B \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$

I proved already that $T_\Bbb R = \begin{pmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix}$ (which mean $T$ reduced to $\Bbb R$ when you look at $V$ as a linear space over $\Bbb R$).

I need to prove that $\det(T_\Bbb R) = |\det(T)|^2$. can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the answer to your [other question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369103/deteminant-of-a-block-skew-symmetric-matrix), we know that
$$
\det(T_\mathbb{R})=\det(A+iB)\det(A-iB).
$$
Now $T=A+iB$ can be seen as a complex matrix with real part $A$ and imaginary part $B$. Denote $\overline{T}=A-iB$.

You just have to convince yourself that $\det \overline{T}=\overline{\det T}$. You can see it directly from the [Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants).

Therefore
$$
\det(T_\mathbb{R})=\det T\cdot \det \overline{T}=\det T\cdot \overline{\det T}=|\det T|^2.
$$

Comment: thanks! sorry I divided my question into 2 different posts I just thought it would be easy once I find what $\det (T_\Bbb R)$ is...
is there another way to show that $\det \overline{T}=\overline{\det T}$ without leibniz formula? cause we didn't learn that...

Comment: @izikgo  What properties/definition of det do you know?

Comment: just the one with the minors

Comment: @izikgo But a minor is a determinant...So do you mean you have a definition by induction on the dimension?

Comment: yes. Laplace expansion.

Comment: @izikgo So when you have to compute an $n\times n$ determinant, you get down to $n-1\times n-1$, then $n-2\times n-2$, until you reach $1\times 1$? I hope you will be presented with a more tractable approach soon...The Laplace expansion is convenient to compute some determinants, but it is not a very interesting "definition".