# Special Block Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, matrix-rank, block-matrices

Let $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be real square matrices. Let construct the $2n$-by-$2n$ block matrix 
$$
Z=\begin{bmatrix}
X&Y\\
-Y&X 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Do the matrices with the block structure of $Z$ have a special name? Does there exist any result on the rank and determinant of these block matrices. This is very similar to [Centrosymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrosymmetric_matrix) matrices.

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the determinant of more general block matrices, the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Properties) may be helpful.

Comment: You can call these matrices block skey-symmetric. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369103/deteminant-of-a-block-skew-symmetric-matrix) gives you an answer about the determinant of these matrices.