# Determinant inequality for skew-symmetric 2×2 block matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, determinant

I've come across the following inequality:

Show that for every pair of square matrices with the same dimensions A and B, the following inequality holds:

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
-B & A
\end{bmatrix}\ge0$$
[Applying elementary operations would result in the following equalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369103/deteminant-of-a-block-skew-symmetric-matrix):
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
-B & A
\end{bmatrix}=\det(A-iB)\det(A+iB)=\det(A^2+i(AB-BA)+B^2)$$
But I can't go any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality holds only for real matrices (let $A=iI_3$ and $B=0$).
With the matrices being real, we have $A-iB=\overline{A+iB}$ (complex conjugate). As a result, we have:
$$\det(A-iB)=\overline{\det(A+iB)}\implies\det(A-iB)\det(A+iB)=|\det(A+iB)|^2=|\det(A-iB)|^2$$
Finally:
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
-B & A
\end{bmatrix}=|\det(A+iB)|^2\ge0$$